# Failed to save 'file.ipynb ': Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'logger')

Tags: amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook, openssh, ssh-tunnel, vscode-remote

So usually i open my terminal and paste a ssh target link like the one below and then open localhost:1234 on some browser like chrome.I use this server to run heavy jupyter notebooks that could potentially fry my laptop. But i wanted to use vscode instead of using my browser.

```
ssh -N -L localhost:1234:localhost:1234 ubuntu@ec2-13-234-456.server-example.compute.amazonaws.com
```

So i connected my vs code to a remote ssh server. **Everything was fine, until i wrote a bunch of code and tried saving it.** When i tried to save the notebook it started giving me this error

> Failed to save 'file.ipynb ': Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'logger')

frankly i'm clueless as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Is your file name file.ipynb?

I had this same problem, which quickly fixed itself when I renamed my file from  'file name.ipynb' to 'filename.ipynb'

Comment: Changing the name to anything works. My file did not have any spaces and I just changed one letter. Problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I copied the .ipynb file for backup and then discarded the error message. The original file didn't change after discarding the error message. I could save changes to the original file again.